# How to set the state of a react functional component using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, use-state

I have a component , which has a form and modal. On click of submit, the modal pops up and on confirmation a call to back end is dispatched.

Initially the modal is hidden by using a state (displayModal).

I am trying to test the API call by finding the button inside display modal. But can't find it as it is not on DOM (display modal is false).

How Can I set the state on jest test.

```
const MyTypeComponent: FunctionComponent<MyType> = ({
props1,
props2,
ownProp1,
ownProp2
}) => {
  //There are two use effects to do something
  //set the modal state
  const [displayModal, setdisplayModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const updateStatusquantityService = () => {
    //Call an API
  };
  const InventoryStatusquantityFormSubmitted = (form) => {
    if (!form.isValid) {
      return;
    }
    //If form valid, display the modal;
  
  };
  return (
    <>
          <Modal
            isOpen={displayModal}
            setIsOpen={setdisplayModalOpen}
            id={"InventoryStatusTypeModal"}
          >
           //Usual Modal stuff and then button
            <Button id={"statusquantityUpdateBtn"} variant="primary" label="Update" onClick={() => updateStatusquantityService()}/>
          </Modal>
          <Form>
             //On form submit, call InventoryStatusquantityFormSubmitted() and display the modal
          </Form>
    </>
  );
};
export default connect(
  (state: RootState) => ({
   //map states to props
  }),
  (dispatch: ThunkDispatch) => ({
    //map props 1 and props 2
  })
)(InventoryStatusquantity);
```

When I am trying to trigger a click even on modal button '`statusquantityUpdateBtn`' by finding it as below, I am getting an empty value as modal is not visible due to it's value.

```
it('Should submit status types form11', () => {
    const submitButtonOnModal = wrapper.find('#statusquantityUpdateBtn').
});
```

I am trying to update the state by using

```
wrapper.instance().setdisplayModalOpen(true)
```

But getting error  `wrapper.instance().setdisplayModalOpen` is not a function.

I am mounting with simple mount command:

```
export const mountWithMemoryRouter = (element: JSX.Element) => {
    return mount(<MemoryRouter>{element}</MemoryRouter>);
};
 
wrapper = mountWithMemoryRouter(
    <Theme>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <MyTypeComponent
                {...defaultProps}
                ownProp1={null}
                ownProp2={null}
            />
        </Provider>
    </Theme>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Those state hooks are scoped to the function, so nothing outside the function can access them. That's why you're getting "is not a function" errors. It's akin to

```
function x() {
   const y = 0
}

x().y // Error
```

I don't see in your code anything that calls `setdisplayModalOpen(true)` in order to show the modal.

Assuming you provided only partial code (but that it's written on your computer), and there is some button or something that runs `setdisplaymodalOpen(true)`, (I'm assuming there's a form submit button) then if I were needing to test this, I would instead use React Testing Library and have something like

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from 'react-testing-library'
import MyComponent from './components/one-to-test'

test('does whatever', async () => {
  render(<MyComponent/>)
  const showModalBtn = screen.getByText('Text of Button You Click to Display Modal')
  fireEvent.click(showModalBtn)
  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText('Update')).not.toBeNull())
  // You are now assured the modal is visible and can continue with the rest of your test
})
```

In this test, you first instruct React Testing Library to render the component that can show/hide the modal (i.e., the form). (Assuming there's a button you click to display the modal), you get that button, and then you simulate a click of that button, and then your test waits for the modal to be visible (in this case, it waits until the "Update" button contained in the modal is visible).

Then you can continue with testing your modal (like clicking the Update button with another `fireEvent.click(updateBtn)`.

If you want to mock out your API, then you could also add

```
jest.mock('./my/api/library', () => ({
  whateverApiCall: jest.fn(() => whateverItShouldReturn)
})
```

Now when you click the form submit button, it will call your mocked API function that returns whatever you defined it to return, and assuming it doesn't throw/reject, your modal will display, and you continue as described above.